# Can I say “across” in the next two situations?

Tags: meaning

Can I say “across” in the next two situations?

> If I sailed the Pacific from Japan to America, making a detour by way
>   of an island, can I say “I went my way **across** to America from Japan?”
>
> If I moved from a stand in a soccer field to the opposite side, making a detour along the round stands (circular path of the arena), can I say “I went my
>   way **across** to the opposite stand from where I was.”

Comment: You can say "across" but you can't say "went" in those cases. You would say "I *made* my way across ..."

Comment: You can say both of those sentences, but neither one is good English. The first is verbose. _I went from Japan to America_ or _I went to America from Japan_ is better. The second sentence doesn't express what the preamble to that sentence says. _I went my way_ is murky; _across to the opposite stand_ is meaningless without a context; _from where I was_ is superfluous. Maybe _I walked across the soccer field and sat on the other side_.

Comment: @BillFranke: I want to know “If I travel in a circular path through seats in an arena to the opposite stand, can I use “across”?

Comment: "Across: to or on the opposite side". Yes, you can say that, but it doesn't sound natural to say _across_ in that situation. If you walked across the soccer field, that's fine. If you circled through the arena to reach the opposite side, it would be more natural to say that you _walked to the opposite side of the arena_. If you walk across the street, I assume you'll take the shortest path. If you live across the street, I'll assume that you live on the opposite side. You walk across a bridge not by getting into the river, wading across through the water, & then getting back onto the bridge.

Comment: I would say that, if you walked through the seats to the other side, you walked not *across* but *around* the field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You go across by going straight over the object in the way.

If you take a circuitous route, you *are* across the ocean but you didn't *go* across the ocean.

So for your first example, you did sail across the ocean. The ocean was involved in the travel.

For the second example, you ended up on the other side of stadium but you didn't get there by traveling over the thing in the way (the field). So you didn't cross the field. But you are across it.

Comment: He did, he went across the ocean; albeit by a circuitous route.